# Catching specific event on carousel

Tags: jquery, carousel, slick.js

I'm trying to make carousel and catch some specific user's action on slide moves on custom events.

- slide restore
- during the touch moves

I tried using [slick](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick), but slick's custom events fires not as I expected.
Here is code I tried.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://rawgit.com/kenwheeler/slick/master/slick/slick-theme.css"/>
 <style type="text/css">
  .slider {
   width: auto;
   margin: 30px 50px 50px; }
 
  .slick-slide {
   background: #3a8999;
   color: white;
   padding: 40px 0;
   font-size: 30px;
   font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica";
   text-align: center; }
 
  .slick-prev:before, .slick-next:before {
   color: black; }
 
  .slick-dots {
   bottom: -30px; }
 
  .slick-slide:nth-child(odd) {
   background: #e84a69; }
 
 </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<section class="slider">
 <div>slide1</div>
 <div>slide2</div>
 <div>slide3</div>
 <div>slide4</div>
 <div>slide5</div>
 <div>slide6</div>
</section>

<div id="log" style="height:300px;overflow-y:auto"></div>

<script>
 $(".slider").slick({
  autoplay: false,
  dots: true
 }).on("afterChange beforeChange edge init reInit setPosition swipe breakpoint", handler);

 function handler(event, slick, direction) {
  var $log = $("#log");
  event.type == "beforeChange" && $log.html("");

  $log.html(event.type +"<br>"+ $log.html());
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**There is no restore events**

When slide isn't reach touchThreshold condition, slide is going back to the last position, but the events are fired in below order.

```
beforeChange -> afterChange -> setPosition
```

whereas for normal slide moves, events are fired like :

```
beforeChange -> swipe -> afterChange -> setPosition
```

The only difference is 'swipe'. To distinguish from normal move and restoring move,
I need to figure out from that difference which is something tedious work.

**There's no way to catch user's touch moves**

When user moves slide during the touch, [there's no custom events firing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbbpz.gif)
 at that point.
The events fires right after when touch is up.

My question is what are the jQuery based carousel plugin to recommend which meet that conditions above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the alternatives is [egjs](https://github.com/naver/egjs/) flicking component based on jQuery.
You can check out basic demo at http://naver.github.io/egjs/demo/flicking/

Here is the sample working demo code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, target-densitydpi=medium-dpi">
 <style type="text/css">
  .slider{height:130px;background-color:grey}
  .eg-flick-panel {font-size:2em;text-align:center}
 </style>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/egjs/1.1.0/pkgd/flicking.pkgd.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<section class="slider">
 <div id="item1" style="background-color:#CC66CC">
  <p>slide1</p>
 </div>
 <div id="item2" style="background-color:#66cccc">
  <p>slide2</p>
 </div>
 <div id="item3" style="background-color:#ffc000">
  <p>slide3</p>
 </div>
 <div id="item3" style="background-color:#f5871f">
  <p>slide4</p>
 </div>
 <div id="item3" style="background-color:#66ff66">
  <p>slide5</p>
 </div>
 <div id="item3" style="background-color:#8a6d3b">
  <p>slide6</p>
 </div>
</section>

<div id="log" style="height:300px;overflow-y:auto"></div>

<script>
 new eg.Flicking(".slider", {
  duration: 300,
  circular: true
 }).on({
  beforeFlickStart: handler,
  flick: handler,
  flickEnd: handler,
  beforeRestore: handler,
  restore: handler
 });

 function handler(event) {
  var $log = $("#log"), direction = { "2": "&larr;", "4": "&rarr;" };

  /^before/.test(event.eventType) && $log.html("");
  $log.html(event.eventType +": "+ direction[event.direction] +"<br>"+ $log.html());
 }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Restore event**

As you noticed running the above code, when slide isn't moved passing threshold the restore events fired in this order:

```
beforeRestore -> flick ... flick -> restore
```

**Touch moves**

And during the touch panel moves, multiple `flick` events are fired as many as your moves and also you can determine direction of the moves with the event parameter value.

The events are fired in this order:

```
(during the touch down moves) flick ... flick -> (when touch is up) beforeFlickStart -> flick ... flick -> flickEnd
```

Hope this answers to your questions.